# Hasura - Permission migrations not applied

Tags: graphql, hasura

Until now, I used the hasura console to update my database schema (new column, table and manage permissions). Every time a change is made, a new migration is created.

Today I added two columns and updated the permissions (`select`/`insert`/`update`).

For some reason, I deleted and recreated my database. Every migrations worked fine but not the permissions. I have my new columns in my tables but the permissions are not persisted and I can't understand why...
The last time I updated permissions, the metadata file changed but not now. I don't really understand this part of hasura, even with the documentation.

Any idea?